# Discord.py rewrite bot not responding to a normal command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a normal command, but I get this error:`Command "leave" is not found`. Here is my code:
I used the reaction-script before, so I know it isn't that.

```
@bot.command
async def leave(ctx):
    user1 = await bot.fetch_user(ctx.message.author.id)
    message = await ctx.send(f"Are you sure that you want to leave {ctx.message.guild}, {ctx.message.author.mention}? React within 30 seconds to verify")
    for emoji in ('✅'):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

        try:
            def check(rctn, user):
                return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '✅'

            rctn, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=30)

            member = ctx.message.author
            await member.kick()
            user = bot.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)
            link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(unique=True, max_uses=1)
            await user.send(f'You left {ctx.message.guild}! But you can rejoin via {link}')

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(f"**Error:** Not reacted in time")
```

Does anyone see the error? I can't seem to find it, as it should work, I think.

Comment: It's `bot.command()` (round brackets missing). Also provide full error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tin Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10053052/tin-nguyen) said, it's
`bot.command()` not `bot.command` as you'd do in a `@bot.event`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper command decorator is `@bot.command()`, and the documentation advises you to use `get_user()` as opposed to `fetch_user()` as the latter is an API call. Also, you can't `user.send()` to use DMs, use `user.dm_channel.send()`

```py
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    user1 = await bot.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)
    message = await ctx.send(f"Are you sure that you want to leave {ctx.message.guild}, {ctx.message.author.mention}? React within 30 seconds to verify")
    for emoji in ('✅'):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

        try:
            def check(rctn, user):
                return user.id == ctx.author.id and str(rctn) == '✅'

            rctn, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check, timeout=30)

            member = ctx.message.author
            await member.kick()
            user = bot.get_user(ctx.message.author.id)
            link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(unique=True, max_uses=1)
            await user.dm_channel.send(f'You left {ctx.message.guild}! But you can rejoin via {link}')

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(f"**Error:** Not reacted in time")
```